# Couldnt reach kibana url after adding ip to interface (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, elastic-stack

I added another ip to the interface for local connections while an elk stack is running. After adding ip i couldn't reach the web url but pods and containers are all working and there is no error log. The problem persists after removing the said ip and going back to the original interface configuration. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hello @Nyquillus, did the solution of Bayu Dwiyan Satria help you?

Answer (score 0):

Most of kubernetes are communication using Container Network Interface (CNI) depends on your CNI network.

Kubernetes have their own subnet for pods and services.

you can dump this info :

```
kubectl cluster-info dump
```

There is possibility the IP that you added to an interfaces is conflict with kubernetes subnets.